# laptop screen suddenly started flickering vertical lines changing colors and frosty letters

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, display, lcd, blank-screen

`laptop` `screen` suddenly   changed with flickering vertical lines changing colors and frosty letters  
this is `HP pavilion dm3t-1000 CTO laptop`  
I am attaching pictures what does it look like is an issue with a `backlight` or the entire screen needs to be replaced or the problem is with
card

`Imgur` where `stackexchange` pictures are uploaded is down. here is a link to `g drive` upload 
[laptop screen issue](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1-WjTwpI4QkKImmSii4eVI4mQ_gFT3YBc)

Comment: Plug an external Monitor into the Laptop, restart and see if that works.  You still need to attach the picture

Comment: Also, take a screenshot & view it on another device.

Comment: The text on the screen in your screen shot is strange. That text effect may have been formed by the Graphics chip (soldered on the the motherboard). Try a different monitor, and also update BIOS, Chipset and Video drivers. See if this helps.

Comment: Remove and re-seat all memory modules several times.

Comment: how would `memory `  module have any bearing the computer runs fine and I can run   s / w . problems is  of a sudden the screen threw up like I mentioned before and also when I tried to connect ` a monitor via HDMI ` externally .... it will not work. along with this few keys also stopped working. I never bothered to observe the latter since I have been always using an `external keyboard ` . could this be `motherboard or graphics chip or the lcd `  based on what's happening outside ?

Comment: ok I changed the ` HDMI `chord and I was able to get normal output on the the `monitor`  . so  I would assume then that the the display card is alright.  please check the Google drive link on the question added additional photos